# Need help with finding all angles of 11 sided 3D object

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, polygons, triangles

**Question**: I'm an artist trying to build a hendecahedron for a project (Image below to see the shape). This object consists of 5 pentagons at the base, 1 pentagon on the bottom, then 5 quadrilaterals on top as the spire that all conjoin at at a point. Can anyone show me a re-usable formula to calculate the angles and lengths of one of the quadrilaterals in the spire given only the length of one side of the pentagons at the base and the size of the pentagon on the bottom and the height I want the spire to be ? lets say each side of one of the bottom pentagrams is one foot.

Here is an image of the Object I am trying to recreate:
[image: mandala light lamp]

**Details**:

I want to re-create a shape similar to the image above no matter how big I chose to make the pentagons on the base or how tall I choose to make the spire. I plan on cutting each face out in cardboard first then fashioning them all together. which is why I need a formula(s) to plug in the length of one hexagon and the height of the spire to give me the angles and lengths of the quadrilaterals I will need to cut out in 2D.

if anyone can point me in the right direction or give me specific dimensions and angles for each face of an object that comes close to that object it would be very very very much appreciated.

Thank you so much for reading and helping me with my project if you choose to do so. I am not a math person, I am leaning on a high school education, I hope my terminology is accurate to the photo.

Comment: This would be better at math.stackexchange.com.  But you have a dodecahedron with a pentagonal pyramid attached, so the formulae at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_dodecahedron will give you a lot of what you need.

Comment: Neil's comment is spot on. From your picture it seems like the base shape is a dodecahedron and then the top 5 pentagons get extended to the apex. In other words, if you cut the spire of the lamp you should get back a dodecahedron. This greatly simplifies your problem, since now all you need to understand is the geometry of the dodecahedron and a pentagonal pyramid.

Comment: This is what I'm talking about: https://images.app.goo.gl/7sWBhncjNZsViyKt7

Comment: Thank you @NeilStrickland . Yes, I realized that last night before bed that if I think of it as a dodecahedron I can just extend the top to a point! I think that's the first time in many years (or maybe ever) I can say I got visually excited about a math problem. The link to the wikipedia article is very helpful!

Comment: @user347489 thank you! I will still have to understand and implement some of this math, but that helps a lot!

Answer (score 9):

There is a problem in the design,
if I understand the phrases "the height I want the spire to be"
and "how tall I choose to make the spire":
these suggest there is freedom to choose the spire height.

[image]

Those quadrilaterals incident to the apex $a$ are not flat for all
apex heights $z$:

[image: Z3]

In general there is a crease along the edge $ac$;
the segment $bd$ is slightly inside the polyhedron.
The crease sharpens as $z$ increases.

So, for a given pentagon edge-length, there is just one $z$ for which the quadrilaterals are flat:
the $z$ achieved by extending the five faces surrounding the top
pentagon of a dodecahedron, as per @user347489's comment.

If the regular pentagon edges are of length $1$,
I calculate $z=3.6034$ above the base,
the distance from $a$ to $b$ is $|ab|=2.61803$,
and the four quadrilateral angles are $108^\circ, 108^\circ, 108^\circ, 36^\circ$.

Comment: yes, this is correct. if the spire height changes the sharpness of the angles for bcd meeting the pentagons as a surface will be sharper or less sharp.... and it may change the geometry because the pyramid extends down into the pentagonal dodecahedron. 

WOW THANK YOU! I will try this version with 108∘,108∘,108∘,36∘ and see how it goes. Your 3D model was spot on, did you create that in a design program, what did you use ?

Comment: I do want to avoid the crease. To clarify, were you saying that edge ac is an unavoidable crease when the height of a as a point on the z index increases too much ? So abcd would no longer be a flat surface like this ? https://www.etsy.com/listing/882883777/gold-lamp-ready-to-ship-flower-of-life

Comment: @JakeMitchell: I used Mathematica to construct the polyhedron. Edge $ac$ disappears exactly when the $z$-height is as I detail, calculated as the extension of the dodecahedron faces. If $z$ is larger, $ac$ is creased; if $z$ smaller, $bd$ is creased.

Comment: I see, yes I didn't realize that! Thank you! This simplifies it a lot though. I only ever have to worry about 1 option.

Comment: Another way to look at the solid is as a full dodecahedron with a pentagonal pyramid on top.  The height of the pyramid has to be chosen so its faces are in a plane with the faces of the dodecahedron.